# where am i going wrong in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope

> I fairly new to javascript and can't figure out the problem with this code

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array1.map(squareit);
let array2;

function squareit(no) {
  array2.push(no * no);
}
console.log(array2);
```

> i have feeling my question is silly but still help me pls

> this is the error i get
> `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'array2' before initialization`

Comment: You need to put `array2` before call function, because when you call it the `array2` doesn't exist.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Error changed to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: `let array2 = [];` instead of `let array2;`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini tysm